# Why is SQL*Developer code editor sluggish?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am accessing SQL*Developer over a VDI and the code editor is very sluggish.  For example, when I type "This is a simple speed test", I type all the keystrokes with NO feedback from UI.  Then, half a heartbeat later, my text appears.

I have tried the following:

1. Edit product.conf to give the JVM more memory
2. Disable DPI settings
3. Disable Code Insight auto-completion options
4. Disable all unused features
5. Change the "look and feel" from Oracle to Windows

I know the problem is to do with SQL*Developer.  When I type in Notepad++ using the same VDI desktop, the responsiveness is fine.

I am running SQL*Developer 21.2.

Are there any settings in SQL*Developer or in Windows that can make this problem go away?  I would like to see each keystroke I type as I type it.

UPDATE: to be more specific -- the SQL*Developer editor does not show anything I type until I stop typing.  If I type fast enough, it can go for 5-10 seconds or longer before updating the UI to show anything.

Comment: I'm guessing Citrix/VDI/networking isn't helping things. Talk to your citrix admin.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks, but I do not have this problem using other editors on the VDI.  Only SQL\*Developer has this problem.

Comment: are your other editors java? b/c java on CItrix is known to be less than fun

Comment: No, I think the other editors are not Java.  I guess I'll have to switch to SQL*Navigator as long as I am on Citrix.  That stinks.

Comment: Or talk to your Citrix admins. We have tons of customers using citrix with SQLDev

Comment: I will do so, but I have nothing to give them idea-wise.  Do you know what kind of changes others have made on Citrix to fix the problem?

Comment: It's usually resources, memory mostly